# Converting Particles to Mesh not working (Blender 2.8)

Tags: particles, conversion

I added some grass particles on a plane and want to turn it into a mesh.

When I press the *convert* button in the Add Modifier menu, nothing happens. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I am working in Blender 2.8 for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a bug in an earlier build of Blender 2.8.
I updated Blender and the convert Particle button works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.79,

After converting the particles to mesh,

You need to Click on the Plane and go back to Particle Tab and remove the Particles on the Plane.

This can also be helpful in 2.8

Comment: Yes, I tried that several times already. The grass just disappears and leaves me with a plain plane. So it is something with this convert button I suppose?